# SSRS Reports - Client vs Server Development

Tags: c#, reporting-services, crystal-reports, reporting

We're currently using Crystal for all our reporting needs, and, for various reasons, we're exploring alternatives. We're looking at client based reporting. I'm comparing C# based reporting tools (like Telerik) to SSRS. I have some light experience with SSRS reports. I have a couple questions regarding these:

1. Is there any difference in the features/functionality available if you are 
   developing reports to be run on the server vs. reports to be run in the client 
   (Microsoft Report Viewer).
2. We're using Visual Studio 2010. Does that contain the very latest Microsoft
   Report Viewer release? If not, where would I get the latest?

Thanks.

Comment: The latest version is 10 that you can download here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a941c6b2-64dd-4d03-9ca7-4017a0d164fd&displaylang=en as I'm not sure if it's included with VS 2010 out the box

Comment: @w69rdy - This appears to be just the runtime deployment. I was more interested in the designer piece that ships with VS 2010. Is this the latest?

Comment: @Randy You said Report Viewer? Ok well if you meant the designer, depends what you want to use as you can use either Visual Studio or Microsoft Report Builder (of which the latest version is 3.0) http://www.microsoft.com/showcase/en/us/details/91919435-1516-49f9-8751-d9d45c641cdd

Comment: @w69rdy - Hmm... I guess this raises another question. What's the difference between the Microsoft Report Builder and what's in VS 2010?

Comment: @Randy Ah it does indeed! As far as I am aware they are both much the same, although they may vary slightly in features. I personally prefer VS as I'm used to its interface but it all comes down to preference really

Comment: @w69rdy - Thanks. I think this probably warrants another dedicated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - The only difference development wise are the options you have available to you for exporting the data

2 - Yes, [2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) would have a report viewer control.

My only advice is to be mindful of the differences between .rdl and .rdlc (.rdl is SSRS, .rdlc is built and stored in the web app, not SSRS, so the rendering is done by the web app).

Comment: I assume you mean that .RDLC reports are rendered by the Microsoft Report Viewer and .RDL reports are rendered by the SSRS engine?